# Rendering HTML in variable using Jade

Tags: node.js, pug

I have some text stored in a variable which contains some HTML.  For example, the <b>cat</b> in the hat. However, when I render it in Jade, it shows up with the tags instead of rendering the formatting. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

> Code buffered by = is escaped by
>   default for security, however to output unescaped return values you
>   may use !=

```
p!= aVarContainingHTML
```

[Pug Doc](https://pugjs.org/language/code.html)

Comment: How can I do this for plain line of text (not a tag)?

Comment: Update: fresh link to documentation https://pugjs.org/language/code.html

Comment: Coulnd't find this on the official pug documentation. Did they leave it out? The section on interpolation is quite short, am I blind? Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 57):

The syntax you need is :

```
!{yourJsVariable}
```

if you use `#{yourJsVariable}` it shows < >, but with `!{}` it doesn't.

Comment: Link to docs: https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html#string-interpolation-unescaped