# How to write html from an oEmbed object directly into a jade template?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, pug

I have an array of objects that each contain a value of raw HTML. The raw html is an [oEmbed](https://instagram.com/developer/embedding/) object, with javascript, css, and html in a single string.

I would like to iterate each string of raw html into css flex boxes, but can't seem to figure out how.

```
<! -- attempt 1 -->
div.container
  h2 posts
    ul.flex-container
    each post in posts         
      li.flex-item
        p!= #{post.html}

<! -- attempt 2 -->
div.container
  h2 posts
    ul.flex-container
    each post in posts         
      li.flex-item 
        include content.html #{post.html}

<! -- attempt 3 -->
div.container
  h2 posts
    ul.flex-container
    each post in posts         
      li.flex-item #{post.html}
```

Attempt #1 stemmed from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11191421/rendering-html-in-variable-using-jade). I get an `Unexpected token ILLEGAL` error on the `p!=` line when I tried that.

I thought I had read something that had said **html** was a built in **filter** for jade.  Couldn't find it anywhere in the [docs](http://jade-lang.com/reference/filters/) though.  Attempt #2 was trying to implement it, but I think I need to have a .html file saved down.  Currently the html is only stored in a variable.

Attempt #3 renders something on the page when I substitute `#{post.title}` for `#{post.html}`, so the error is not in the `each post in posts` function.

Can jade handle a direct html write? Would I be better off trying to use `document.body.innerHTML` in a function and see if I can inject it to the flex boxes that way?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading some documentation from [Jade Attributes](http://jade-lang.com/reference/attributes/) and [Jade logic tutorial](http://cssdeck.com/labs/jade-templating-tutorial-codecast-part-2), i hope this answer will help you :

***Node.js***
Just call `node server.js` to see the output.

*file : sever.js*

```
var jade = require('jade');
var data = [
  {"extId":"eg1" , "html":"<div>Everything you want 1<script>alert('hello1');</script></div>"},
  {"extId":"eg2" , "html":"<div>Everything you want 2<script>alert('hello2');</script></div>"},
  {"extId":"eg3" , "html":"<div>Everything you want 3<script>alert('hello3');</script></div>"},
];

var html = jade.renderFile('testing.jade', {posts : data , pageTitle : 'TestingJade'});

console.log('html : ' , html);
```

*file : testing.jade*

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
  head
    title= pageTitle
  body
    h1 Jade - node template engine
    ul
      each post ,index in posts 
        - var curId = post.extId
        li(id= curId)= post.html
```

Read the docs i provide, it will help you to understand.
The use of `index` in `each post ,index in posts` seem to be important !
After that we define a variable handling the "ID", like that we can set it to the tag using the '*attributes*' definition.
And at last, we set the content using `=` to escape the `post.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>TestingJade</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Jade - node template engine</h1> 
  <ul>
    <li id="eg1">&lt;div&gt;Everything you want 1&lt;script&gt;alert('hello1');&lt;/script&gt;&lt;/div&gt;</li>
    <li id="eg2">&lt;div&gt;Everything you want 2&lt;script&gt;alert('hello2');&lt;/script&gt;&lt;/div&gt;</li>
    <li id="eg3">&lt;div&gt;Everything you want 3&lt;script&gt;alert('hello3');&lt;/script&gt;&lt;/div&gt;</li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

---

Note that if you don't want to escape the content of `post.html` use `!=`

```js
li(id= curId)!= post.html/*
             ^
instead of   |
             v 
li(id= curId)= post.html*/
```

the output should be :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>TestingJade</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Jade - node template engine</h1> 
  <ul>
    <li id="eg1">
      <div>Everything you want 1
        <script>
          alert('hello1');
        </script>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li id="eg2">
      <div>Everything you want 2
        <script>
          alert('hello2');
        </script>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li id="eg3">
      <div>Everything you want 3
        <script>
          alert('hello3');
        </script>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

---

So transposing it to your code :

```html
<! -- attempt 4 -->
div.container
  h2 posts
    ul.flex-container
      each post, index in posts         
        li.flex-item= post.html
```

Comment: Thank you ! Think i was failing to understand the concept of escaping content !