# How to pass strings of HTML as elements in an array to Jade with Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, node.js, pug

Basically I am coding a blog engine in Nodejs with express4 and jade, and I wish to be able to pass the posts as strings of html to jade, to then loop through them.

I have populated an array with valid strings of html like `console.log(items[0]); // prints: <h1>test</h1>`
however I cannot get my head around how I would print out the html within a DOM.

So far I have tried to make the array global and do something like

```
each item in items
  item
```

or simply `#{items}`
however these methods print out html with < > notation in, and duplicates the data like

```
&lt;<h1>test</h1>&gt;<!--<h1-->test&gt;
```

I have also tried to pass the html through as a parameter in routes like `res.render('index', {items: items});`, however this has exactly the same effect

My guess is that perhaps I am trying to render html outside of the html domain, so it can do it but it obfuscates the data. Any suggestions would be appreciated!!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found this: [Rendering HTML in variable using Jade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11191421/rendering-html-in-variable-using-jade)

For yours I believe it would be `p!= item`