# MongoDB emits HTML as plain text

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, express

Why isn't my html being rendered whenever I output the result from a query.

This is how I save the document:

```
data = {
    title: "Article title",
    body: "<b>This</b> is the content!!"
};

var article = new Article(data);

article.save();
```

And this is how I display it:

```
h2.articleTitle(style="font-style: italic;") #{article.title}
p.articleBody(style="margin-top: 20px;") #{article.body}
```

The out of the article body should be:
 **This** is the content!!

But instead it outputs everything, including the html tag: <b>This</b> is the content!!

I was reading another similar question asked that told me to add a dash (-) before article.body. This is what I tried:

```
h2.articleTitle(style="font-style: italic;") #{article.title}
p.articleBody(style="margin-top: 20px;") 
    - article.body
```

But this didn't output anything when I tried it this way. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It has nothing to do with database. Learn how your template engine works to output raw html.

Comment: @AlexBlex Thanks for the comment, I searched up how to fix it using my template engine. It's working now. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the problem was how I was outputting with Jade, the template engine I'm using. I managed to fix this replacing the # to the ! symbol.

```
h2.articleTitle(style="font-style: italic;") #{article.title}
p.articleBody(style="margin-top: 20px;") !{article.body}
```

Original answer: [Rendering HTML in variable using Jade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11191421/rendering-html-in-variable-using-jade)