# node js write html variable to jade template

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, callback, pug

I have a `javascript` function in `node js` that queries a database and returns a `json` array to a callback function.  That callback function then formats that `json` into a pure `html` table and saves that information to a variable.  What would be the best way to get that html table into the `jade` template? I want to render that `HTML` table in the page.

```
function getData() {

var sql = require("mssql");
var dbConfig={
        server:"server",
        database: "db",
        user:"user",
        password: "pw"
}




        var conn = new sql.Connection(dbConfig);
        var req = new sql.Request(conn);
        conn.connect(function (err){
                if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return;
                }


                req.query("SELECT * FROM table",resultsCallback)

                conn.close();
        });

}

function resultsCallback (err, recordset) {

        var tableify = require('tableify');

        if (err) {
                console.log(err);
        }
        else {

                var html = tableify(recordset);
                html = html.replace('<table>','');
                html = html.replace('</table>',');

        }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Note: You don't need to change the return value of tableify, you just need to use != instead of = look at link :
[Rendering HTML in variable using Jade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11191421/rendering-html-in-variable-using-jade#answer-11191512)

While rendering your jade file, you can try passing the function in your route something like this:

-------- routes.js --------

```
router.get ( '/' , function(req,res){
    res.render(index,{
        table: getData()
    });
});

getData = function(){
    ...
}
```

-------- view.jade --------

```
!= table//rendering your table where table is of html format
```

!= will render the correct html, not a string